# Flink KPL doesn't seem to deliver to second shard

Tags: scala, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

So I have the following code where I am trying to get the KPL to set the partition key, so I can start sharding my stream.

```
    def createSinkFromStaticConfig(stream: Option[String], region: Option[String]): FlinkKinesisProducer[String] = {
        val outputProperties = new Properties
        outputProperties setProperty(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, region.get)
        outputProperties setProperty("Region", region.get)
        outputProperties.put("RecordTtl", s"${Int.MaxValue}")
    
        outputProperties.put("ThreadPoolSize", "5")
        outputProperties.put("MaxConnections", "5")
        val sink = new FlinkKinesisProducer[String](new SimpleStringSchema, outputProperties)
        sink setDefaultStream stream.get
        sink setDefaultPartition "0"
        sink setCustomPartitioner new KinesisPartitioner[String]() {
          override def getPartitionId(element: String): String = {
            val epoch = LocalDateTime.now.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            epoch.toString
      }
    }
    sink setQueueLimit 500
    sink
}
```

So the sink, when called, does work and sends to data to the stream.  I have manually sharded the stream and have two consumers on it.  I can see each consumer is being assigned to different shards, but only one will get any work.  Is there something I am doing wrong to set the shard?  IS there a way to validate which shard it was sent to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found some fun.

So the above code does work, and submits to different shards.  My problem was that the second task of my kinesis consumer was somehow reading the parent shard, instead of grabbing on of the available child shards.  once I spun up a 3rd task, then I had one for each child and parent.  Still no good, but at least I know its not the producer!

EDIT:

so for more clarification, this was a problem of my own making (aren't they all?).  In testing, I had sharded and unsharded a bunch of times on the stream for testing.  This caused the parent to be considered still active, and needing processing.  Even without all that shenanigans, it could of been a problem.  See the link

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/issues/786